# htacces rewrite tld without changing subdomain or dirs

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite the following url:

the subdomain should match any subdomain. same for the TLD.
both: http://car.example.com/ and http://cat.example.co.uk should be rewritten

http://subdomain.example.com/some/dir
to
http://subdomain.example.nl/some/dir

and
http://example.com/some/dir
to 
http://exampkle.nl/some/dir

(also with www. adress)

but my knowledge of htaccess and rewrite rules in general aren't good enough for this :(

I hope one of you knows the solution.

ps. I did try a search ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge comes with having to detect and account for four different possible domain patterns:

- example.com → example.nl
- example.co.uk → example.nl
- sub.example.com → sub.example.nl
- sub.example.co.uk → sub.example.nl

So, what this ruleset does is checks that the TLD is not .nl (preventing a loop from occurring), then pulls the subdomain, www or not, off the front (read as "capture anything other than a dot followed by a dot, optional), followed by the base domain, followed by a dot. We don't have to match the entire URL, since we aren't keeping the TLD.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example\.nl$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.)?example\.
RewriteRule ^ http://%1example.nl%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R=301]
```

The RewriteRule's ^ matches any URL, then inserts the contents of the first set of parens in the preceding RewriteCond (the subdomain) with %1, and completes the rewriting by appending the requested path and flags to ignore case, make this the last rule, and redirect with a search-engine-friendly 301, ensuring the rewritten URL appears in the user's browser. Any query string (text appearing after a ? in the URL) is automatically included by default.

Comment: Almost! had a infinite loop because you did not stop the rewrite if the TLD was correct. added RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([^.]+\.)?example\.nl -- Now it stops if the TLD is correct. Also, amazing first answer! welcome to SO

Comment: Actually not my first answer on this site — just the first to be acknowledged.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
**EDIT:** See changes to subdomain, using %1 to capture from RewriteCond

```
RewriteEngine On
# Check if the hostname requested is subdomain.example.com or empty
# Now we attempt to capture the subdomain with (.*)? and reuse with %1
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
# Rewrite it as subdomain.example.nl and redirect the browser
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1example.nl$1 [L,R,NE,QSA]

# Note: With the above edit for %1, this part should no longer be necessary.
# Then do the same for example.com, with or without the www
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.nl$1 [L,R,NE,QSA]
```

Comment: Updated my question a little bit. The subdomain and TLD are "unknown" (well, not exactly. but right now there are 14 different subdomains on 3 different TLDs which should all be rewritten to the .nl TLD with the same subdomain AND suffix). If this is impossible thats a shame, I will be using your snipper a lot of times :)

Comment: See my changes above.  This is untested, but I think it will work.

Comment: While you did adress for the change in subdomain you did not adress for the tlds. Thanks for your help tho :) the post by Eric3 was (in part) the solution